# SQS throughout is very low with lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, message-queue, amazon-sqs

I have a SQS queue where i have piled up 100000 messages and i want to how fast i can dequeue from that queue using lambda function .
To dequeue this many messages i am able to achieve 17k messages per minute and it invokes only 600 lambda functions.

So is there any way to improve the queue operation ?
Lets say if we can increase lambda function invokation by 5k then my dequeue will be faster as well .

Average time taken by lambda function is 20 MS only and i have also given max memory to lambda function

This is my lamda function which i enabled trigger after we have 100000 messages in queue .

```
package com.amazonaws.lambda.demo;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.SQSEvent;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.SQSEvent.SQSMessage;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.PublishRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.PublishResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQS;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.SendMessageRequest;

public class LambdaMysql implements RequestHandler<SQSEvent, Void> {

    @Override
    public Void handleRequest(SQSEvent event, Context context) {

        for (SQSMessage msg : event.getRecords()) {
            JSONObject jsonResponseObjectMain = new JSONObject(msg.getBody());
            String ID = jsonResponseObjectMain.get("ID").toString();
            System.out.println("------ID-------" + ID);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            AmazonSQS sqs = AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard()
                      .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
                      .build();

            String bodyofJson = "Record Inserted Into FSP DB";
            String queueUrl="https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/***-queue";
            SendMessageRequest send_msg_request = new SendMessageRequest()
                    .withQueueUrl(queueUrl)
                    .withMessageBody(bodyofJson);
            sqs.sendMessage(send_msg_request);

        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: What batch size (up to 10) do you have configured? What concurrency do you have configured for the Lambda function? Do you need to write this in Java?

Comment: The numbers you have listed aren't really adding up. If the average invocation is 20ms, as you stated, then one lambda could process 50/sec, which would be 3,000/minute. That's with one lambda and a batch size of one. If the batches were maxed out at 10 and it was still running in 20ms then you'd process 30K in one minute, with one lambda.

Comment: Why is your code sleeping for 2 seconds?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thats the latency i will have when i will run in real application

Comment: @JasonWadsworth i dont know why but i am able to run only max 600 lambda concurrently .

Comment: @jarmod yes the default size is 10 And yes i have to do this in java .I have not configured any concurrency in lambda ..Its by default .Can i set any

Comment: The default configuration is 1000 concurrent Lambda functions. Given that your functions are quite short in duration, there might be added overhead in triggering new functions so quickly. You could experiment by requesting an increase in the number of concurrent functions. See also: [AWS Lambda Function Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/scaling.html)